# ASP.NET project not creating .mdf file in app_data

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm following along with the Coding With Mosh Vidly tutorials, and I've gotten to the point of building the database, and the .mdf file is not being generated within the app_data folder.

I've got through and made sure all the azure extensions etc are all installed, ran update-database and i get the 'Running Seed Method' response.

Not sure if the mdf file is being saved elsewhere, or if i have done something wrong, but some help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run the following command from Package Manager console.

```
update-database
```

Also, ensure to check connection strings. one way is to enter the same connection string in SQl server management console and see if you can login.